# Play 2: How to test controllers with non-empty request body

Tags: scala, testing, playframework-2.0

I can't figure out how to test controllers (functional testing) in Play 2.3.

The problem is that controller I want to test doesn't see my request body.
Example code:

```
--- //contents of a specs2 example
"simple controller test" in new WithApplication {
  val requestBody = JacksMapper.writeValueAsString(Map("client_uuid" -> "uuid"))
  val request = new FakeRequest(
    POST, controllers.routes.EventsController.createEvent().url,
    FakeHeaders(Seq(CONTENT_TYPE -> Seq("application/json"))), requestBody)

  println(request.body) // => {"client_uuid":"client"}

  val result = route(request).get
  println(contentAsString(result)) // => {"client_uuid":["This field is required"]}
}

--- //Overall code was stripped down for greater clarity
```

I don't understand why I get validation error when I do provide "client_uuid" in request. 
Maybe someone can point me into the right direction? Is there a simple way to write functional tests (like in Rails, maybe)?

**Edit**: controller source code

```
object EventsController extends Controller {
  def createEvent = Action { implicit request =>
    val eventForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithError => BadRequest(formWithError.errorsAsJson),
      event => //persist event
    )

   val eventForm = Form(single("client_uuid" -> nonEmptyText))
  }
```

P.S. If I directly call controller method I get the same result.
P.P.S. The API method works fine in development.

Comment: Since you are using the Form API, it would be helpful to see how you are handling JSON in your controller.

Comment: @MariusSoutier I added related controller code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is the JSON string is not correctly encoded. I'd try using Play's JSON API directly:

```
import play.api.lib.json._
val requestBody = Json.obj("client_uuid" -> JsString("uuid"))
val request = new FakeRequest(
  POST, controllers.routes.EventsController.createEvent().url,
  FakeHeaders(Seq(CONTENT_TYPE -> Seq("application/json"))), requestBody)
```

Comment: No your original String was missing surrounding double quotes. You can test that using curl.